# Vue3 component: this.$store is typed but this.$store.getters is not typed

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuex, vuejs3

There's a vue3/vuex4 application with the following definition:

`shims-vue.d.ts`:

```js
export {}

declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  import { ThStore } from '@/domain/store/store'
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: ThStore
  }
}
```

Then the `$store` is used in a component in a very straightforward way:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { ThStore } from '@/domain/store/store'

export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    user() {
      const store1 = this.$store as ThStore
      const store2 = this.$store
      const user1 = store1.getters[`${MODULES.AUTH}/${GETTERS.CURRENT_USER}`]
      const user2 = store2.getters[`${MODULES.AUTH}/${GETTERS.CURRENT_USER}`]
      console.log(user1, user2)
      return user1
    }
  }
})
```

It gives a very strange result: `store1` which is explicitly set as `ThStore` works just fine, `user1` is typed. `store2` is also typed, but `store2.getters` has `any` type, hence `user2` is not typed.

[image]

How that can be that two typescript objects which have the same type are differently typed for the inner property?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move import to the upper scope:

```js
import { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
import { ThStore } from '@/domain/store/store'

export {}

declare module 'vue' {
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: ThStore
  }
}
```